# How can I optimize canvas performance for a 60fps emulator?

Tags: javascript, performance, html5-canvas

I want to write a gameboy emulator in JavaScript. The screen resolution is `160 x 144`. It has four shades of colors: black, dark gray, light gray, and white. The gameboy has a screen refresh rate of 60fps.

I have a `screen` array which has a size of `160*144=23040`, where each index stores a color shade from 0-3.

To render the screen to the user, I want to use the HTML5 canvas.
From what I understand, the most straightforward way to do this is to create an [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object with a `Uint8ClampedArray` RGBA bitmap and pass it to the canvas via `putImageData`.

In order to do this, every frame I have to transform my screen to a `Uint8ClampedArray`, and transform each shade into their respective 4 byte RGBA numbers. This new RGBA bitmap would be `(160 * 144 * 4 bytes per pixel = 92160` in size:

```
function screenToBuffer(screen) {
  return Uint8ClampedArray.from(screen.map(shade => shadeToRGBA(shade)).flat());
}
```

Then, this buffer is passed to a user-supplied callback function where they would display it to the canvas like so:

```
onFrame: function(frameBuffer) {
  var image = new ImageData(frameBuffer, 160, 144)
  ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
}
```

This works fine in theory, but it is a naive approach and I have discovered that it's not efficient at all. By using the profiler, the `screenToBuffer` function alone takes ~25ms. If the screen is going to be updated at 60fps, it will need to render every 16.6ms!

What is the best way to approach this problem? Creating an entirely new 92kb `Uint8ClampedArray` and mapping 23,000 color shades per frame is way too costly.

I want to keep the `screen` array because it is smaller and much easier to reason about in my code than a `Uint8ClampedArray`. I imagine that it would be better to initialize a `Uint8ClampedArray` once, and update it whenever there is a change to the `screen` array. That way I can simply return the RGBA buffer on each frame and it should be already be synced with my screen.

I also wonder if creating a new 92kb `ImageData` object every frame is also resource intensive and if there might be a better way to handle that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Bundle up draw calls and save a color palette ahead of time and you shouldn't have too much of an issue with this.

Take a look at my snippet below:

```js
//Generate output node for time
var output = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
//Generate canvas
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.style.width = "500px";
//Setup canvas
canvas.width = 160;
canvas.height = 144;
//Generate color pallette
var colors = ["black", "#444", "#ccc", "white"]
    .map(function (b) {
    ctx.fillStyle = b;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
});
//Generate framedata (referencing back to one of our 4 base colors)
var data = [];
while (data.length < canvas.width * canvas.height) {
    data.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4));
}
//draw function
function drawCanvas() {
    //Start time
    var t = Date.now();
    //Fill with basic color
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //Prepare ImageData
    var frame = new ImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //Loop through buffer
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var dataPoint = data[i];
        //Skip base color
        if (dataPoint == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        //Set color from palette
        frame.data.set(colors[dataPoint], i * 4);
    }
    //Put ImageData on canvas
    ctx.putImageData(frame, 0, 0);
    //Output time
    output.textContent = (Date.now() - t).toFixed(2);
    //Schedule next frame
    requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
}
//Start drawing
drawCanvas();
//Start simulation at 60 fps
setInterval(function () {
    data = data.map(function () { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); });
}, 16);
```

I consistently get about 2ms per frame.